# pushd command issues inside a windows batch file

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file

I have Windows C# program which spawns a process to call a batch file which in turn calls a batch file (located on a different drive) using the pushd command

```
@ECHO Obfuscation progress. >> %LOG_FILE%
@ECHO ------------------------------------------------------ >> %LOG_FILE%
pushd "%WORK_DIRECTORY%\"
@ECHO %ERRORLEVEL% ERRORLEVEL
@ECHO Successfully entered the Work directory. >> %LOG_FILE%
@ECHO CALL %OBF_DIG_SIGN_FILE% >> %LOG_FILE%
CALL %OBF_DIG_SIGN_FILE%
popd
```

where the **%WORK_DIRECTORY%** - location where the **%OBF_DIG_SIGN_FILE%** batch file is present.

Although it seems the batch file executes, because I can see the Obfuscated dlls in the output folder. Two issues crop up which is eating my head since morning.

```
1.  @ECHO commands post pushd command doesnt work, nothing is seen in the log
2.  The control doesn't return, i.e. **popd** doesn't execute for some reason
```

Any ideas what might be happening for the control is not being redirected back to the main batch file.

Though the above set of commands works perfectly fine with the command line.

Comment: Are you using an absolute path for %LOG_FILE%?  If %LOG_FILE% is a relative path maybe the echo lines following pushd are written to a different file relative to %WORK_DIRECTORY%.

Comment: I agree with @mcdon about checking the LOG_FILE variable. While you are at it, you should quote all paths that could ever possibly contain a space character. `CALL "OBF_DIG_SIGN_FILE%" >>"%LOG_FILE%"`

Comment: Your `CALL %OBF_DIG_SIGN_FILE%` will never return if the called batch script issues an EXIT command. It will only return properly if `EXIT /B` is used.

Comment: @mcdon : The %LOG_FILE% refers to just a file name (BUILD_LOG_MM.DD.YYYY.log) and not to an absolute path. The file is logged in the same directory from where the script is currently being executed.

Comment: @Liturgist: I have tried both with or without using quotes. None of which seem to work.

Comment: @dbenham: The %OBF_DIG_SIGN_FILE% batch file script has the EXIT /B line in the end. But still the issue remains. Funny thing is that if I run the  batch files manually i.e. starting by double clicking the batch file from explorer ( not by C# application invoking it) it works perfectly fine.

Comment: If your %LOG_FILE% is just a file name, then that is definitely the source of your "dissapearing" log output. It must be the full path if you want your current code to work. Not sure why your CALL is not returning.

Comment: I made an interesting observation. I created a sample console application from where I invoked this %OBF_DIG_SIGN_FILE% script passing the required arguments. The script hung just before the line where I make call for obfuscation batch file. But as soon as I closed the console application, the %OBF_DIG_SIGN_FILE% started executing.

Comment: Is there a "BUILD_LOG_MM.DD.YYYY.log" file in %WORKING_DIRECTORY%?  I'd assume it's first line would be "Successfully entered the Work directory."

Comment: @mcdon: Nope, it doesn't